# MySQL 8 Regular expression binary problem

Tags: mysql

My app using a third party library which has it's own internal database management system. It tries to find a row from a table by a query that looks like:

> ... REGEXP BINARY 'somequery';

It can't find the row looking for, I checked the row, it was there, and looked [mysql regexp documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html), even their example doesn't work in mysql 8. I tried the same query in version 5.7 and it works!

```
mysql> SELECT 'a' REGEXP 'A', 'A' REGEXP BINARY 'A';
+----------------+-----------------------+
| 'a' REGEXP 'A' | 'A' REGEXP BINARY 'A' |
+----------------+-----------------------+
|              1 |                     0 |
+----------------+-----------------------+
```

> $ mysql -V mysql  Ver 8.0.12 for osx10.13 on x86_64 (Homebrew)

Is there something I understand wrongly?

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_%';
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                                     |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4                                                   |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4                                                   |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                                                   |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                                    |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4                                                   |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                                                   |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                                      |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/local/mysql-8.0.11-macos10.13-x86_64/share/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: On my end, I'm getting `(1, 1)` for that query. Show us `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE  'character_set_%';`

Comment: Hmm, no idea - replicated your charset and I still get (1, 1). On MariaDB though; so maybe it's a MySQL bug?

Comment: I am using the same shell to perform query, I expect same encoding/decoding for both 'A', if I would insert into a table(utf8mb4) and query from a shell(utf8) or vice versa that would be the reason, but in the same shell it shouldn't be encoding problem, am I right?

Comment: First I thought it is a bug until I saw the example in the doc, no one puts not-working example in a documentation, I assume.

Comment: Note: the doc might inherit from older versions.

Comment: There is incompatible regexp changes in version 8.0.4, that might cause the problem. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-4.html